# How do I make Jekyll exclude my config.rb for SASS?

Tags: jekyll

In Jeky'll's `_config.yml` file I have the following at the bottom: `exclude: README.md, css/config.rb`

It excludes the README fine, but not the config.rb file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a problematic feature of Jekyll [for quite some time](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/906).

Just to be sure: what version of Jekyll are you using? The latest ones enforce correct YAML handling, so you should be using the array syntax (`exclude: [README.md, config.rb]`).

It's possible with the current implementation to use glob syntax and exclude a whole directory (or tree of directories or whatever), but I couldn't find an issue or documentation on how to exclude a specific file in the filesystem.

In any case, you can exclude `config.rb`. I assume you don't have another one in your site, and even if you have, you probably don't want it to be on `_site`. This is bad overall, but works. Your exclude rule would be `exclude: [README.md, config.rb]`.

Comment: Jekyll 1.1 was my version, and the array syntax seemed to work. Thank you very much. :)